# why console gives in this sequence?

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am making a mern ecommerce website i just want to see how useEffect works so i console.log in some part of useEffect  and loadFilteredResults i saw that --->
initial
entry
skip
entry1

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73MG0.png)

but i think it shoud be-->
initial
entry
entry1
skip

why console give this?? i am a begginer, i am a self learner , so please if you need any extra info please comment.

code snippet-->

```
  const loadFilteredResults = (newFilters) => {
          console.log("entry")
        getFilteredProducts(skip, limit, newFilters).then((data) => {
           console.log("entry1")
          if (data.error) {
            setError(data.error);
          } else {
            //console.log(data);
            setFilteredResults(data.data);
            //console.log("size-->");
            //console.log(data.size);
            setSize(data.size);
            setSkip(0);
          }
        });
      };
    ....
    ....
    useEffect(() => {
        init();
        console.log("initial");
        loadFilteredResults(skip, limit, myFilters.filters);
        console.log("skip");
      }, []);
```

//full code of shop.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import Card from "./Card";
import { getCategories, getFilteredProducts } from "./apiCore";
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
import RadioBox from "./RadioBox";
import { prices } from "./fixedPrices";

const Shop = () => {
  const [myFilters, setMyFilters] = useState({
    filters: { category: [], price: [] }
  });
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(3);//prpduct lesss so use 3 but sir used 6
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0);
  const [size, setSize] = useState(0);
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);

  const init = () => {
    getCategories().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        //console.log("error");
        setError(data.error);
      } else {
        //console.log("set");
        //console.log(data);
        setCategories(data);
        //console.log(data);
      }
    });
  };

  const loadFilteredResults = (newFilters) => {
    //console.log(newFilters);
      console.log("entry")
    getFilteredProducts(skip, limit, newFilters).then((data) => {
      console.log("entry1")
      if (data.error) {
        setError(data.error);
      } else {
        //console.log(data);
        setFilteredResults(data.data);
        //console.log("size-->");
        //console.log(data.size);
        setSize(data.size);
        setSkip(0);
      }
    });
  };

  const loadMore = () => {
    console.log("skip"+skip);
    console.log("limit"+limit);
    let toSkip = skip + limit;
    console.log("toSkip"+toSkip);
    getFilteredProducts(toSkip, limit, myFilters.filters).then((data) => {
      //console.log("filter");
      //console.log( myFilters.filters)
      if (data.error) {
        setError(data.error);
      } else {
        //console.log(filteredResults);
        //console.log(data.data);
        setFilteredResults([...filteredResults, ...data.data]);
        //console.log("after");
        //console.log(...filteredResults);
        //console.log(filteredResults);
        //console.log(filteredResults);
        //console.log([...filteredResults])
        //console.log([...filteredResults, ...data.data])
        setSize(data.size);
        setSkip(toSkip);
      }
    });
  };

  const loadMoreButton = () => {
    return (
      size > 0 &&
      size >= limit && (
        <button onClick={loadMore} className="btn btn-warning mb-5">
          load more
        </button>
      )
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    init();
    //console.log(skip);
    console.log("initial");
    loadFilteredResults(skip, limit, myFilters.filters);
    console.log("skip");
  }, []);

  const handleFilters = (filters, filterBy) => {
    //console.log("SHOP", filters, filterBy);
    const newFilters = { ...myFilters };
    //console.log(newFilters);
    newFilters.filters[filterBy] = filters;
    //console.log(typeof(filters));

    if (filterBy === "price") {
      let priceValues = handlePrice(filters);
      newFilters.filters[filterBy] = priceValues;
      //console.log(priceValues);
    }

    //console.log(myFilters.filters);

    loadFilteredResults(myFilters.filters);

    setMyFilters(newFilters);
  };

  const handlePrice = (value) => {
    const data = prices;
    let array = [];
    //console.log(value);
    for (let key in data) {
      if (data[key]._id === parseInt(value)) {
        array = data[key].array;
      }
    }
    return array;
  };

  // const x = (filters)=>{
  //   console.log("filters:"+filters);
  //   handleFilters(filters, "category")
  // }

  return (
    <Layout
      title="Shop Page"
      description="search and buy books of your choice"
      className="container-fluid"
    >
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-4">
          <h4>Filter by categories</h4>
          <ul>
            {/* below will be show in list show we wrap it in unorder list */}

            <Checkbox
              categories={categories}
              handleFilters={(filters) =>
                handleFilters(filters, "category")
              }
            />
          </ul>

          <h4>Filter by price range</h4>
          <div>
            <RadioBox
              prices={prices}
              handleFilters={(filters) => handleFilters(filters, "price")}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-8">
          <h2 className="mb-4">Products</h2>
          <div className="row">
            {filteredResults.map((product, i) => (
              <Card key={i} product={product} />
            ))}
          </div>
          <hr />
          {loadMoreButton()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

Comment: Does `getFilteredProducts` involve a network (axios, fetch, xhr etc) call ?

Comment: yes , fetch from backend

Comment: @NiceBooks even if it didn't the fact it's a promise should be evidence enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFilteredProducts` must be a `Promise`. Please read [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

> Callbacks added with then() will never be invoked before the
> completion of the current run of the JavaScript event loop.

Comment: getFilteredProducts is a promise, so it execute after back from useEffect?

Comment: No, the callback inside the `then` will be executed after useEffect.

Comment: means first go in useEffect print initial, then go for loadFilteredResults print entry,then go in getFilteredProducts but not then(),after that go in useEffect print skip,then go for then,after that it repeats entry,entry1 ??

Comment: getFilteredProducts fetched from backend

Comment: getFilteredProducts code for fetch from backend-->

Comment: export const getFilteredProducts = (skip,limit,filters={}) => {
  
  const data={
    skip,limit,filters
  }
  return fetch(`${API}/products/by/search`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

Comment: If it's repating logging entry entry1 (which you didnt mention in the question), it means `loadFilteredResults`called from some other point again.

Comment: yes i didnot mention but before repeatation , whatever i said is correct?